# Tukey-Lambda Distribution versus Student's t Distribution

Tags: distributions, references

On Wikipedia and many other sites, it is mentioned that

> The Tukey lambda distribution is actually a family of distributions
>   that can approximate  a number of common distributions. For example,
>
> $\lambda = -1$ approx. Cauchy
>
> $\lambda = 0$ exactly logistic
>
> $\lambda = 0.14$ approx. normal
>
> $\lambda = 0.5$ strictly concave
>
> $\lambda = 1$ exactly uniform(-1, 1)
>
> $\lambda = 2$ exactly uniform
>   (-1/2, 1/2)

a) I couldn't find the derivation of these Tukey values and correspondence to the other distributions anywhere on the net. Even Wikipedia didn't state the source for this. Would anyone know where were these claims originally derived?

b) Would anyone have any idea of what distribution would a Tukey lambda distribution with $\lambda$ of -0.5 correspond to? Or, how to go about finding this?

c) Would anyone have any idea of what values of $\lambda$ for Tukey lambda distribution can correspond to Student's t-distribution? Or, how can I go about finding this?

Comment: The $\lambda=0,1,2$ cases are utterly trivial. The approximations would not be derivations as such. One can see for oneself how good the approximation to the normal is easily enough by looking at a normal Q-Q plot for a large sample, or indeed more directly - e.g. in R via `p=ppoints(10000);` `x=((p)^.14-(1-p)^.14);` `qqnorm(x)`, though slightly smaller values of $\lambda$ work better in the extreme tail. Similarly one can check the Cauchy approximation: `p=ppoints(10000);` `x=-((p)^(-1)-(1-p)^(-1));` `plot(qcauchy(p),x)` (though it's hard to see the detail near the center on that scale)

Comment: Tukey's original paper is a technical report: Tukey, J. (1960). The Practical Relationship Between the Common Transformations of Percentages of Counts and Amounts, Technical Report 36. Statistical Techniques Research Group, Princeton University.  ... there are many references in Ramberg et al (1979) "A Probability Distribution and Its Uses in Fitting Data".Technometrics, 
Vol. 21, No. 2 (May), pp. 201-214